# Triggered Send from Cloud Page not sending email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send

I have some ampscript that works fine when in its own cloudpage:

```
%%[
VAR @ts, @tsDef, @ts_sub, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode, @id
SET @id = REQUESTPARAMETER('id')

SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")

SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "PostDOILoyaltyNUEN")
SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)

SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @id)

AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)

SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)

]%%
```

But when I add it to a more complex cloudpage that contains other logic, it doesn't work.

```
%%[
VAR @sfid, @lan, @exp, @result, @today, @valid, @len, @ts, @tsDef, @ts_sub, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode, @id, @ts_statusMsg
SET @sfid = REQUESTPARAMETER('sk')
SET @lan = REQUESTPARAMETER('ln')
SET @id = REQUESTPARAMETER('id')
SET @exp = REQUESTPARAMETER('expiry')
SET @today = FormatDate(Now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')

SET @len = Length(@sfid)
IF EMPTY(@sfid) THEN
 redirect(CloudPagesURL(890))
ELSEIF @len != '18' THEN
 redirect(CloudPagesURL(907))
ELSEIF EMPTY(@lan) THEN
    redirect(CloudPagesURL(908)) /*redirects  to error page*/
ENDIF

IF @exp > @today THEN
SET @valid = TRUE
SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('MAG_Subscription__c', @sfid, 'MAG_Status__c', 'Verified')
SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('MAG_Subscription__c', @sfid, 'MAG_VerifiedDate__c', @today)
SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('MAG_Subscription__c', @sfid, 'Welcome_Email__c', 'TRUE')
ELSE
SET @valid = FALSE
ENDIF

SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")

SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "PostDOILoyaltyNUEN")
SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)

SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @id)

AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)

SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)

]%%
```

It doesn't make sense why it wouldn't work. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on 'It doesn't work'. Is there an error? nothing sends? etc?

Comment: my bad. was linked to the wrong cloudpage. d'oh

Answer (score 0):

email was linked to the wrong cloudpage. d'oh

Comment: This answer is in the Low Quality Posts review queue. I recommend you either add more detail here (e.g. "Make certain you check Some > Config > Path") or just delete both question and answer.